# Disable Carousel Prev Next buttons

Tags: jquery

Hello I need to disable Previous and Next anchors in the following script if it show first and last div respectively. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHC4X/3/) for it.
I have several anchors which shows the corresponding div when clicked. I also have Previous and next anchors which when clicked go to next and previous divs respectively.

I am looking to disable "Prev" in case it is showing the first div ie div0 and to disable "Next" in case it is showing the last div ie div4. Also please let me know if the code is broken somewhere.
Thanks

```
    <a class="prev">prev</a>  &nbsp;
    <a class="next">next</a>
    <a class="anc" id="an0">A1</a>
    <a class="anc" id="an1">A2</a>
    <a class="anc" id="an2">A3</a>
    <a class="anc" id="an3">A4</a>
    <a class="anc" id="an4">A5</a>



    <div class="zdivs">
            <div id="q0" class="hidepiece">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            <div id="q1" class="hidepiece">
                 consectetuer adipiscing elit
            </div>
            <div id="q2" class="hidepiece">
                sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt 
            </div>
            <div id="q3" class="hidepiece">
                laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
            </div>
            <div id="q4" class="hidepiece">
                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam
            </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the jQuery for hiding all divs with class name 'hidepiece' and show them one by one on clicking anchors

```
<!--One by one navigation class anc hidepiece-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.hidepiece").hide();
$("a.anc").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var divId = id.replace("an", "q");
    $("div.hidepiece").hide();
    $("div#" + divId).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#zdivs").scrollTop(0);//scrolls zdiv to top
  });
});
</script>

<!--previous next class zdivs-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".zdivs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$(".next").click(function(){
  $("#zdivs").scrollTop(0);
    if ($(".zdivs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".zdivs div:visible").next().fadeIn("slow").prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".zdivs div:visible").hide();
        $(".zdivs div:first").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    return false;
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
  $("#zdivs").scrollTop(0);
    if ($(".zdivs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".zdivs div:visible").prev().fadeIn("slow").next().hide();
    else {
        $(".zdivs div:visible").hide();
        $(".zdivs div:last").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `</br>` what's that tag?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Where do you see a line break tag?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. @ManofSnow it's in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks I updated it; just wondering why it was still working there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is all you need:

```js
$('.Gal').each((i, Gal) => {

  let c = 0; // Counter to keep track of current slide index
  
  const
    $slides  = $('.Gal-slides > *', Gal),
    $prev    = $('.Gal-prev', Gal),
    $next    = $('.Gal-next', Gal),
    $buttons = $('.Gal-nav button', Gal),
    
    tot = $slides.length,
    anim = () => {
      $slides.removeClass('is-active').eq(c).addClass('is-active');
      $buttons.removeClass('is-active').eq(c).addClass('is-active');
      // Comment the following lines if you want always PREV/NEXT visible
      $prev.toggle(c > 0);
      $next.toggle(c < tot - 1);
    };
    
  $prev.add($next).on('click', ev => {
    c = ev.currentTarget == $next[0] ? ++c : --c;
    if (c > tot - 1) c = 0;
    if (c < 0) c = tot - 1;
    anim();
  });
  
  $buttons.on('click', ev => {
    c = $buttons.index(ev.currentTarget);
    anim();
  });
  
  anim(); // init 

});
```

```css
.Gal {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.Gal-slides > * {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Gal-slides > *.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Gal-prev,
.Gal-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.Gal-prev { left: 0; }
.Gal-next { right: 0; }

.Gal-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Gal-nav button.is-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gal">

  <div class="Gal-slides">
    <div class="is-active">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>2 consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    <div>3 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt</div>
    <div>4 laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</div>
    <div>5 Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="Gal-prev">Prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="Gal-next">Next</button>

  <div class="Gal-nav">
    <button type="button" class="is-active">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gr8 its working there but I am unable to work it on my pc. I downloaded jquery2 still I can't get it to work. I included jquery2 then added this code but when I open the local file with chrome I see all 5 divs,

Comment: Thanks I could get it to work, I included the code just before body and it works but why it didn't work when I added it in head. I tried 4 or 5 times in head then suddenly I copied it before body.

Comment: @swapna that's cause we're supposed to **always** wrap our jQuery code inside a `ready function` read: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info editeds my answer to reflect. So remember, always use the document.ready

Comment: Ok but in my actual page there are five groups of anchors which show or hide the same zdiv. ie anchor id an0 to an9 show div id q0 to q9; an10 to an15 show div id q10 to q15... and so on; is there a way I can show or hide div according to anchor and div ids'...OR... to span anchors across different sections in a web-page.Thanks.

Comment: otherwise just modify the code to, instead of `.index()` grab the clicked element `data-*` attribute

Comment: yes but I only need to span anchors not zdiv. say zdiv have 40 parts q0 to q39, and anchors will be spanned in 5 sections having 8, 10 12 or whatever number of elements.

Comment: @swapna (ah, like a pagination?) as I said, instead of grabbing the `index` get the number out of a data attrigube like `data-target="3"`

Answer (score 0):

Check the visibility of Div - q0 and Div q4.

```
if (!$("").css('visibility') === 'hidden') { }
```

Accoridng to the return value enable and disable next and prev buttons